# Parsing Graphviz's Dot language

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm searching for a Dot language (http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) parser in Objective-C or C but I cannot find one. Any advice ?

I do not want to draw graphs, but to use the Dot language to describe a workflow.

Comment: I'd say you'd most likely have to make one yourself. I have made several graph libraries myself before, but I've never come across this language before. You may be better off starting your own open-soruced project and finding people to help you make it go.

Comment: [ParseKit](https://github.com/itod/parsekit)

Comment: Thanks for this ideas, I will have a look at this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is open source, so it's parser is available...

Comment: Great, I thought that GraphViz only provides graphs drawing.